# mydb not defined but it is?

Tags: python, database

Iam actually discovering DB management with py.
But i have some issue in my code :

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="siteDB",
    )
except(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError):
    print('DB crée')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

The code return this `NameError: name 'mydb' is not defined` but i think it is.
Can someone explain me why it is angry ?

Comment: Did you hit the exception? If the connect failed, the variable would not be defined.

Comment: Please post the entire output. Then we can see whether the error print happened and if the error is at the line we assume it is.

Comment: nothing like that the DB is connect, no prob with this point

Comment: You should either move the code that uses `mydb` inside the `try`, or exit the script when the exception happens.

Comment: `DB crée
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Marc\Projet Site\dbmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
NameError: name 'mydb' is not defined`

Comment: You got the `DB  crée` error! That means it didn't connect.

Comment: Print the error message to see the reason why it couldn't connect.

Comment: HO okay i got it he didnt find it that it but how can i create and get it at the same time ?
the error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'sitedb'`

Comment: You can leave out the `database` argument to `connect()`. Then you can create the DB from Python.

Comment: Okay thx to you and for your time